# how to create multiple git branches in a single command?

Tags: git, bash

On my local I have master checked out.

I am trying to use a bash script-tag and using git to create
alpha_1, alpha_2, alpha_3 branches from master and push it to remote.

Is this possible with one or two lines or very few?
example: `git checkout -b alpha_1 alpha_2 alpha_3 && push all`

I know i can manually do this by

```
git checkout -b alpha_1
git checkout -b alpha_2
git checkout -b alpha_3

git push origin alpha_1
git push origin alpha_2
git push origin alpha_3
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: part of the build process. Every time a new dev pushes his/her feature to only certain branches. I need to delete and recreate branches everyday which is painstaking.

Comment: I'm not so sure I understand your pain.  Describe your scenario a bit more so that you could get an answer that would best suit you.  Right now, it kind of sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Sure. Each developer pushes his/her code to either alpha_1 or alpha_2 or alpha_3. We then analyze each alpha branch, if the branch is good to go for production we merge to master and delete the branch. Then we recreate alpha_1, alpha_2, alpha_3 the next day. Also branch names change each day. The process starts again

Comment: Why can't each developer just make their own branch when they start working on a new feature or bug fix?

Answer (score 7):

```
for branch in alpha{1..3}; do git checkout -b $branch; done; git push origin --all
```